# Secondary Axis in ggplot does not seem to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

I am trying to plot hourly volume of cyclists from two different datasets. One that contains the actual values from count station data, and another that has fitted mean hourly counts following a cosine wave. I know it is not best practices to include a secondary axis, however, the fitted mean counts are very low and I want to show how they compare to the real, observed relationship. Currently ggplot does not appear to be plotting the mean counts on a secondary axis.

Here is the code I have used:

```
ggplot()+
 geom_point(cycle_open_18_hourly, mapping = aes(x = hour_of_day, y = hourly_count), alpha = 0.05)+
 geom_smooth(cycle_open_18_hourly, mapping = aes(x = hour_of_day, y = hourly_count), method = "loess", se = F)+
 geom_line(fitted_together, mapping = aes(x = hours, y = mean), color = "firebrick")+
 scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 5)))+
 facet_wrap(.~direction)
```

[image: Which gives me a graph that looks like this]

But the mean counts do not appear to be plotted on the second axis. The peak mean count is ~25 and the line does not reach 25.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!!!!

Edit: Here is the cycle open dataset

```
    month day hour_of_day direction wday hourly_count season month.f westbound_hourly eastbound_hourly
1       1   1           0 Eastbound  Mon            4 Winter       1               NA                4
2       1   1           0 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
3       1   1           1 Eastbound  Mon            0 Winter       1               NA                0
4       1   1           1 Westbound  Mon            1 Winter       1                1               NA
5       1   1           2 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
6       1   1           2 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
7       1   1           3 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
8       1   1           3 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
9       1   1           4 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
10      1   1           4 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
11      1   1           5 Eastbound  Mon            5 Winter       1               NA                5
12      1   1           5 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
13      1   1           6 Eastbound  Mon            0 Winter       1               NA                0
14      1   1           6 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
15      1   1           7 Eastbound  Mon            2 Winter       1               NA                2
16      1   1           7 Westbound  Mon            0 Winter       1                0               NA
17      1   1           8 Eastbound  Mon            3 Winter       1               NA                3
18      1   1           8 Westbound  Mon            0 Winter       1                0               NA
19      1   1           9 Eastbound  Mon            4 Winter       1               NA                4
20      1   1           9 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
21      1   1          10 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
22      1   1          10 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
23      1   1          11 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
24      1   1          11 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
25      1   1          12 Eastbound  Mon            0 Winter       1               NA                0
26      1   1          12 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
27      1   1          13 Eastbound  Mon            2 Winter       1               NA                2
28      1   1          13 Westbound  Mon            5 Winter       1                5               NA
29      1   1          14 Eastbound  Mon            2 Winter       1               NA                2
30      1   1          14 Westbound  Mon            4 Winter       1                4               NA
31      1   1          15 Eastbound  Mon            2 Winter       1               NA                2
32      1   1          15 Westbound  Mon            6 Winter       1                6               NA
33      1   1          16 Eastbound  Mon            6 Winter       1               NA                6
34      1   1          16 Westbound  Mon            5 Winter       1                5               NA
35      1   1          17 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
36      1   1          17 Westbound  Mon            4 Winter       1                4               NA
37      1   1          18 Eastbound  Mon            2 Winter       1               NA                2
38      1   1          18 Westbound  Mon            3 Winter       1                3               NA
39      1   1          19 Eastbound  Mon            3 Winter       1               NA                3
40      1   1          19 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
41      1   1          20 Eastbound  Mon            4 Winter       1               NA                4
42      1   1          20 Westbound  Mon            0 Winter       1                0               NA
43      1   1          21 Eastbound  Mon            4 Winter       1               NA                4
44      1   1          21 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
45      1   1          22 Eastbound  Mon            1 Winter       1               NA                1
46      1   1          22 Westbound  Mon            2 Winter       1                2               NA
47      1   1          23 Eastbound  Mon            4 Winter       1               NA                4
48      1   1          23 Westbound  Mon            0 Winter       1                0               NA
49      1   2           0 Eastbound  Tue            2 Winter       1               NA                2
50      1   2           0 Westbound  Tue            1 Winter       1                1               NA
51      1   2           1 Eastbound  Tue            1 Winter       1               NA                1
52      1   2           1 Westbound  Tue            2 Winter       1                2               NA
53      1   2           2 Eastbound  Tue            0 Winter       1               NA                0
54      1   2           2 Westbound  Tue            0 Winter       1                0               NA
55      1   2           3 Eastbound  Tue            3 Winter       1               NA                3
56      1   2           3 Westbound  Tue            0 Winter       1                0               NA
57      1   2           4 Eastbound  Tue            0 Winter       1               NA                0
58      1   2           4 Westbound  Tue            0 Winter       1                0               NA
59      1   2           5 Eastbound  Tue            2 Winter       1               NA                2
60      1   2           5 Westbound  Tue            0 Winter       1                0               NA
61      1   2           6 Eastbound  Tue            4 Winter       1               NA                4
62      1   2           6 Westbound  Tue            1 Winter       1                1               NA
63      1   2           7 Eastbound  Tue            3 Winter       1               NA                3
64      1   2           7 Westbound  Tue            3 Winter       1                3               NA
65      1   2           8 Eastbound  Tue            1 Winter       1               NA                1
66      1   2           8 Westbound  Tue            8 Winter       1                8               NA
67      1   2           9 Eastbound  Tue            1 Winter       1               NA                1
68      1   2           9 Westbound  Tue           27 Winter       1               27               NA
69      1   2          10 Eastbound  Tue            6 Winter       1               NA                6
70      1   2          10 Westbound  Tue           25 Winter       1               25               NA
71      1   2          11 Eastbound  Tue            3 Winter       1               NA                3
72      1   2          11 Westbound  Tue           13 Winter       1               13               NA
73      1   2          12 Eastbound  Tue            3 Winter       1               NA                3
74      1   2          12 Westbound  Tue           12 Winter       1               12               NA
75      1   2          13 Eastbound  Tue            4 Winter       1               NA                4
76      1   2          13 Westbound  Tue            7 Winter       1                7               NA
77      1   2          14 Eastbound  Tue            7 Winter       1               NA                7
78      1   2          14 Westbound  Tue            8 Winter       1                8               NA
79      1   2          15 Eastbound  Tue            8 Winter       1               NA                8
80      1   2          15 Westbound  Tue            8 Winter       1                8               NA
81      1   2          16 Eastbound  Tue           13 Winter       1               NA               13
82      1   2          16 Westbound  Tue           10 Winter       1               10               NA
83      1   2          17 Eastbound  Tue           19 Winter       1               NA               19
84      1   2          17 Westbound  Tue            3 Winter       1                3               NA
85      1   2          18 Eastbound  Tue           32 Winter       1               NA               32
86      1   2          18 Westbound  Tue            5 Winter       1                5               NA
87      1   2          19 Eastbound  Tue           21 Winter       1               NA               21
88      1   2          19 Westbound  Tue           15 Winter       1               15               NA
89      1   2          20 Eastbound  Tue           19 Winter       1               NA               19
90      1   2          20 Westbound  Tue            8 Winter       1                8               NA
91      1   2          21 Eastbound  Tue           12 Winter       1               NA               12
92      1   2          21 Westbound  Tue            9 Winter       1                9               NA
93      1   2          22 Eastbound  Tue            6 Winter       1               NA                6
94      1   2          22 Westbound  Tue            4 Winter       1                4               NA
95      1   2          23 Eastbound  Tue            3 Winter       1               NA                3
96      1   2          23 Westbound  Tue            3 Winter       1                3               NA
97      1   3           0 Eastbound  Wed            4 Winter       1               NA                4
98      1   3           0 Westbound  Wed            5 Winter       1                5               NA
99      1   3           1 Eastbound  Wed            2 Winter       1               NA                2
100     1   3           1 Westbound  Wed            1 Winter       1                1               NA
```

If more is needed I can try and upload the full dataset.

Fitted data:

```
  hours    hr_sum    hr_adj      mean direction
1      0  24548.11  67.25510  6.137390 Eastbound
2      1  22585.11  61.87703  5.647922 Eastbound
3      2  21837.64  59.82915  5.462404 Eastbound
4      3  22241.51  60.93566  5.564902 Eastbound
5      4  23831.75  65.29247  5.964301 Eastbound
6      5  26738.47  73.25608  6.693273 Eastbound
7      6  31167.36  85.39004  7.803361 Eastbound
8      7  37351.70 102.33341  9.352924 Eastbound
9      8  45457.98 124.54242 11.383472 Eastbound
10     9  55435.32 151.87758 13.881894 Eastbound
11    10  66829.26 183.09387 16.733885 Eastbound
12    11  78635.43 215.43953 19.687420 Eastbound
13    12  89315.43 244.69982 22.357027 Eastbound
14    13  97078.33 265.96802 24.294560 Eastbound
15    14 100401.20 275.07177 25.119670 Eastbound
16    15  98578.05 270.07684 24.657000 Eastbound
17    16  92000.17 252.05526 23.005845 Eastbound
18    17  81998.90 224.65453 20.500251 Eastbound
19    18  70346.83 192.73103 17.583933 Eastbound
20    19  58699.48 160.82049 14.670682 Eastbound
21    20  48231.90 132.14220 12.053773 Eastbound
22    21  39551.05 108.35905  9.884371 Eastbound
23    22  32807.86  89.88455  8.199757 Eastbound
24    23  27882.15  76.38946  6.969618 Eastbound
25     0  22943.03  62.85761  5.736930 Westbound
26     1  18775.59  51.43998  4.696054 Westbound
27     2  16152.51  44.25346  4.041097 Westbound
28     3  14758.56  40.43440  3.693380 Westbound
29     4  14410.41  39.48056  3.607197 Westbound
30     5  15060.64  41.26203  3.770820 Westbound
31     6  16797.30  46.02001  4.206384 Westbound
32     7  19844.24  54.36779  4.969973 Westbound
33     8  24552.44  67.26696  6.149418 Westbound
34     9  31355.89  85.90654  7.853197 Westbound
35    10  40650.76 111.37196 10.180132 Westbound
36    11  52560.54 144.00149 13.160543 Westbound
37    12  66602.07 182.47143 16.672775 Westbound
38    13  81385.09 222.97284 20.368283 Westbound
39    14  94601.57 259.18239 23.669450 Westbound
40    15 103536.76 283.66234 25.897840 Westbound
41    16 106038.18 290.51556 26.516587 Westbound
42    17 101460.03 277.97267 25.365980 Westbound
43    18  90970.14 249.23327 22.739374 Westbound
44    19  77002.34 210.96532 19.245688 Westbound
45    20  62236.30 170.51041 15.554408 Westbound
46    21  48732.58 133.51391 12.179822 Westbound
47    22  37589.78 102.98569  9.395807 Westbound
48    23  29072.25  79.65000  7.267979 Westbound
```

Comment: Please add `cycle_open_18_hourly` to your code to make it reproducible

Comment: Sorry, how do I go about doing that? Edit: I posted the first 100 rows if that helps! Sorry for not posting it first.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Does only plotting mean work?

`ggplot()+
 geom_line(fitted_together, mapping = aes(x = hours, y = mean), color = "firebrick")+
 scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 5)))+
 facet_wrap(.~direction)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It didn't seem to work on my machine, the geom_line still does not fit to the secondary axis. I'll try restarting my R session to see if that helps.
Edit: Restarting did not fix the issue. Thank you again!

Comment: On looking again, I am not sure if the code is doing what you expect. The secondary axis are the original values divided by 20, so it will not give you the mean values from the data frame. Can you clarify why you want 2 axes? I'm not sure if I follow the reason.

Comment: Sure. Sorry for not being clearer. I'm trying to have the hourly counts from the actual cyclist counts (cycle open dataset) on the main y-axis. I want the mean counts from the fitted dataset to be plotted on the secondary axis, as these values are much smaller than the observed hourly counts. 
I know having two axes isn't best practices, but as it stands the mean values are very hard to make out and interpret.

Comment: In that case do you not need to multiply the mean values by 20 prior to plotting?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood how the secondary axis worked. I originally thought the dividing by 20 would divide the primary axis values by 20, but does the command divide the count values?

Comment: The OP stated that the line does not reach 25 on the secondary axis. This seems to be because the larges value for mean is 25, but this value is 25/20 on the secondary axis

Comment: I see. I had originally thought by the secondary axis would divide the primary axis values by 20 (e.g. 900/20, 600/20 etc.). This is it now
```ggplot()+
  geom_point(cycle_open_18_hourly, mapping = aes(x = hour_of_day, y = hourly_count), alpha = 0.05)+
  geom_smooth(cycle_open_18_hourly, mapping = aes(x = hour_of_day, y = hourly_count), method = "loess", se = F)+
  geom_line(fitted_all, mapping = aes(x = hours, y = mean * 10), color = "firebrick")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 5)))+ 
  facet_wrap(.~direction)```

Comment: That's how I would solve it

Comment: I think that the approach in general is probably causing more problems than the axis. Try looking at separate seasons, as they are going to impact outdoor activities very heavily. A separate plot for each season would be more useful. Simple changes in daylight and temperature make 7:00 PM a different event in summer and winter.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment sconfluentus. I do have the data set up so I can look seasonally, but right now my supervisor just wants me to prepare an estimate of hourly counts.